# Is there a movie that is based on or very similar to Robert Heinlein's "Tunnel in the Sky"?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, adaptations, tunnel-in-the-sky

One book that I've always wished there was a good movie for, was Robert Heinlein's *Tunnel in the Sky*. I was just wondering if there was ever a movie adaptation that they maybe changed the name and I just missed it. Is there a movie based on *Tunnel in the Sky*, or a movie very similar?

---

This question is not off topic, I'm not asking for a list of works. I was simply asking if there had been a movie based on *Tunnel in the Sky*, but perhaps under a different name. For example, the way the sci-fi horror movie *The Thing* is based on a novella/short story called "Who Goes There". If I asked 'Is there a movie based off the short story "Who Goes There", then the answer would be *The Thing*.

Comment: I, too, would love to see good movies based on the juveniles.  The chances of both "movie" and "good" are pretty small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very hard to prove a negative, so for what it's worth, I will just tell you:  No, there has never been a movie adaptation.

The only films based on Heinlein works are [The Brain Eaters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brain_Eaters) (plagarized), [Destination Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destination_Moon_(film)), [Predestination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film)), and [The Puppet Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters_(film)).

Oh, and as [Yasskier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/50522/yasskier) pointed out, the unfortunate [Starship Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_%28film%29) adaptation.

Comment: And the "Starship troo..." oh wait...

Comment: Maybe one day... :) Thanks a bunch, at least I have peace of mind

Comment: Thanks, I had mercifully forgotten that one.  Editing it in for completeness.

Comment: I thought The Puppet Masters was surprisingly good.  It diverged from the book in many ways, but was a decent movie on its own.

Comment: Wow I did not know predestination was based on a Heinlein book. No wonder I liked it! Thanks